# Apache Rewrite with variables in Query String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a two part problem that I have only been successful with the first part.
I have the following listed in .htaccess which works great:

```
RewriteRule ^senior/?$  demo.php?dID=1 [NC,L]
```

So visitors can go straight to mysite.com/senior and the correct internal page (demo.php?dID=1) gets pulled up.

My problem is that I also would like a rewrite where /demo.php?dID=1 shows up in the URL bar as /senior.  So existing links show up with the new user friendly url.

My attempt so far has been:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}           ^dID=1$
RewriteRule ^demo.php$   senior [NC] 
RewriteRule ^senior/?$  demo.php?dID=1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match against the request instead of the query string and redirect the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  \ /demo\.php\?dID=1($|\ |&)
RewriteRule ^demo.php$   /senior? [NC,R] 
RewriteRule ^senior/?$  /demo.php?dID=1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Actually there's a slight error above.   If the ID being passed is 1 or 11, it matches 1, not 11.  Same if the id is 8 or 86, it matches 8.

Comment: @Ryan see the additional regex element for the condition

Answer (score 0):

Place this additional rule before your current rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+demo\.php\?dID=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /senior? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^senior/?$ /demo.php?dID=1 [NC,L]
```

Your current rule based on `QUERY_STRING` will loop since internal rewrite rule will populate the QUERY_STRING and both rule will keep triggering each other.

Comment: I tried your solution also, and it ended up redirecting to the following page:  http://www.mysite.com/var/www/vhosts/6yfw-lwnd.mysite.com/httpdocs/senior.  Jon Lin's solution worked up above, but I greatly appreciate your effort too!

Comment: @Ryan: It was actually due to missing leading slash which I have edited now.